# AddClass issues on mobile

Tags: jquery

I am adding a class to a link to signify that it's been selected. This works fine on a desktop, however when trying on a mobile device it doesn't seem to change the class of the link.

```js
$('.valuation-option').on('click', function() {
  $(".valuation-option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('-selected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('-selected');
    }
  })

  $(this).addClass('-selected');
  var type = $(this).data('type');
  $('.type').val(type);

  return false;
})
```

```css
.valuation-option:active,
.valuation-option.-selected,
.valuation-option.selected {
  background: #c59b52;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.cta,
.button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 52px;
  border: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .cta,
  .button {
    padding: 14px 22px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.cta.-primary,
.button.-primary {
  background: #c03;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.cta.-primary:hover,
.button.-primary:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background: #ff0040;
}

.cta.-secondary,
.button.-secondary {
  background: #c59b52;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="cta -primary d-inline-block mr-2 mt-1 mt-sm-0 valuation-option" data-type="Sales" href="#">I'm Selling</a>
<a class="cta -primary d-inline-block mb-2 mt-1 mt-sm-0 valuation-option" data-type="Lettings" href="#">I'm Renting</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m3epth8n/

Comment: why do you prefix your class with `-` ?

Comment: CSS BEM Modelling

Comment: that's not BEM style

Comment: Ok, thanks - Is that effecting the jQuery!?